# space between buttons to fit page size

Tags: html, css, button

Is it possible to have the 3 buttons below spaced to fit any size page? I want to keep the same button size, just making the space between the buttons larger or smaller depending on the screen size. Anything, helps.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 150px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:125px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <h4>Contact us</h4>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Sub-Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this below in `.fieldset`

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

---

#### Snippet

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 150px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 125px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <h4>Contact us</h4>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Sub-Category</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify these declarations :

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:125px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    display:block;
    width:33.333333%;
    float:left;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 150px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:125px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    display:block;
    width:33.333333%;
    float:left;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <h4>Contact us</h4>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Sub-Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <input placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this in your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    input {
      width:100%
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an explanation of what your code does and why it would fix OP's issue. Thanks.